# Providing default value for function prop in React

Tags: reactjs

What is the best way to handle optional `React.PropType.func` properties?

Should I provide default noop for it (if so what's the best way) or should I just check if the prop is defined?

```
propTypes: {
    onClick: React.PropTypes.func
},

someMethod: function() {
    if (this.props.onClick) {
       this.props.onClick();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React has [getDefaultProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#default-prop-values). Then you can call onClick without errors.

```
getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
        onClick: function() {}
    };
}
```

Comment: ES6 class syntax for the same:

"static defaultProps = {
  onClick: () => {}
};"

Answer (score 11):

i am using anonymous empty arrow function...
correct me if this is stupid :)

```
component.defaultProps = {
  foo: () => {},
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do with `typeof`:

```
if (typeof this.props.onClick === 'function'){
    //...
}
```